# Are you missing a assenbly reference

Tags: asp.net, rdlc

I am using RDLC report in my project.

```
protected void btnview_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ReportViewer1.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Local;
        ReportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportPath = Server.MapPath("~/Report.rdlc");
        MyDataset dsreceipt = GetDataItem("select * from tblGeneratedReceipt ");
        ReportDataSource datasource = new ReportDataSource("Receipt", dsreceipt.Tables[0]);
        ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
        ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(datasource);

    }

    private MyDataset GetDataItem(string p)
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(p,conn);
        SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        MyDataset rec = new MyDataset();
        adp.Fill(rec, "DataTable1");
        return rec;
    }
```

I am getting error on line 
private MyDataset GetDataItem(string p) 
Error is about Missing assembly reference

Comment: Have you defined the class `MyDataset`????

Comment: check spelling of assembly in title

Comment: Paste the actual error message. And, include the using statements in you code so we could understand the problem better

Comment: @AbdulRahmanAnsari   MyDataset is MyDataset.xsd file

Comment: Just use `DataSet` instead of `MyDataset`

Comment: Can you tell us which assembly ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've seen something similar to this with the ReportViewer control; can you check that you have the *correct versions* of the following in your bin directory: -

- Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common.dll
- Microsoft.ReportViewer.ProcessingObjectModel.dll
- Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms.dll
- Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms.dll